# Ограничение количество одновременных подключений с клиента в Golang GRPC

Tags: golang, concurrency, grpc

я новичок в GRPC и у меня стоит задача:
Необходимо написать сервис на Golang работающий по gRPC.

Сервис с функциями:

1. Принимает изображения от клиента и сохраняет их.
2. Выводит список загруженных файлов.

Как ограничить количество одновременных подключений с клиента:

- на загрузку/скачивание файлов - 10 конкурентных запросов;
- на просмотр списка файлов - 100 конкурентных запросов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Создаете в вашем grpc сервере буферизированный канал емкостью 10

   limiter := chan(struct{}, 10)
2. При запросе на загрузку/скачивание отправляете туда пустую структуру

   limiter <- struct{}{}
3. После того как запрос отработает вынимаете ее оттуда

   <- limiter

Таким образом вы никогда не сможете запустить одновременно больше 10 запросов на загрузку/скачивание.

Comment: Спасибо я думал что в самом GRPC есть какой то функционал для данных целей.

Comment: В GRPC есть интерцепторы, которые позволяют делать общую обработку запросов (например логгирование, добавление данных в контекст и пр.). В вашем случае логика работы напрямую связана с конкретным запросом и поместить ее нужно именно в запрос.